# Google Maps services and traffic limits

Tags: ios, google-maps, mapkit

I'm planing to create an app to locate the user favorite place in iOS. I think to use Google Maps as it is more accurate. It is a simple app and I don't think that it will give me enough money to purchase a paid version of Google Maps plan. I checked in previous answers in stack-overflow and in the terms of usage of Google, it seems that for tracking user location I should contract a plan or the other option was 1.000 request per day. I got confused at this point. If someone has experience with Google Maps could tell me if a simple app can use a free maps service or should I change to Apple MapsKit? How should I calculate the number of request my app will do if it tracks the position of user to see if he is near to someplace?

Thanks,

Comment: Where do you read that you need google to track the location of a user

Comment: Dr.Molle, yes, you are right. I can track the user location with Core Location framework and check if user has enter or exit a specific point. But I would like to show a map with user position and when I do this I will make a request to Google. So I need to estimate the number of request to calculate if I can use the Standard Plan that is free. I would like some opinion about that. But thanks for comment, you just clarified a point.